# Django transitive closure generates wrong SQL

Tags: python, django

I have the models

```
class Person(models.Model):
    # some fields

class Chat(models.Model):
    people = models.ManyToManyField(Person)
    # some fields
```

and I want to generate a queryset of all the people who share at least one conversation with some given person.

I tried

```
Person.objects.get(pk=2).chat_set.values_list('people').distinct()
```

But that gives me `[(2,)]` when it should be `[(1,),(2,),(3,)]`.

I then tried

```
print(Person.objects.get(pk=2).chat_set
    .values_list('people').distinct().query)
```

and that gave me

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT "webapp_chat_people"."person_id" FROM
"webapp_chat" INNER JOIN "webapp_chat_people" ON (
    "webapp_chat"."id" = "webapp_chat_people"."chat_id" )
WHERE "webapp_chat_people"."person_id" = 2
```

This is clearly wrong! How do I work around it? I would rather not do any kind of "select n+1." I'm using version 1.7.7, do I need to upgrade?

Comment: As a guess (I need to sleep and can't test), what does Person.objects.filter(chat__people=Person.objects.get(pk=2)) give?

Comment: @RemcoGerlich That totally worked. Good call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just copying @RemcoGerlich comment as an answer here:

```
Person.objects.filter(chat__people=Person.objects.get(pk=2))
```